# Is there any way to clear out my busy airport so I can upgrade it?

Tags: openttd

I really want to upgrade this airport, because it's causing some big backlogs for me. However, it's so busy that there are constantly airplanes either loading/unloading, in the hangar waiting or circling to land. This means I can't delete to rebuild. Is there any way I can clear it out temporarily to allow me to demolish/rebuild?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you click on the airport, in the details screen there is a 'Close Airport' button. Next to the 'Rename Airport' button I believe.

This will stop planes from landing (it'll skip the destination in their orders) which lets you do the in situ upgrade.

Comment: If you're quick enough, you can also demolish a station and build another over it. The new station will retain the details of the first and the vehicles will return when their orders next dictate it.

Comment: As an addendum to my answer, I believe the 'close airport' button is introduced in the version 1.3 beta - so it doesn't apply to the current release version (1.2.3 at time of answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to have all the planes dock somewhere else, which would take a lot of time.

A possibly easier thing to do is to build a temporary airport to accomodate a place for the aircraft to be during the upgrade. What I mean with that is that you replace this airport with the temporary airport in the airplanes directions.